# Threads working at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to make my class as Queue such that if I have **two threads**, one that adds and other that removes elements - they could do that at the **same time**. Currently one gets blocked because the threads are competing for the same lock object.

```
public class Queue {

    private Cell head, tail;

    public synchronized void add(Object o){
        Cell c = new Cell(o);
        if (tail == null) { head = c; }
        else { tail.next = c; }
        c.next = null;
        tail = c;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Object remove() 
    throws InterruptedException {
        while (head == null){
        wait();
    }   
        Cell c = head;
        head = head.next;
        if (head == null){ tail = null; };
        return c.contents; 
    }
}

class Cell {
    Cell next;
    Object contents;
    public Cell(Object o) { contents = o; }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Queue q = new Queue();

    Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                q.add(new Integer(i));
        }

    });
    Thread thr1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                try {
                    q.remove();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    });

    thr.start();
    thr1.start();

}
```

Comment: Firstly, don't name your own classes after [existing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interfaces. Secondly, your question is...?

Comment: As far as I understand one of the threads blocks while the other works and vice versa and I want to make them both working all the time.

Comment: @Nikola in order to preserve consistency of your queue, only one thread must work on it at the given time (mutual exclusion property). So, it's not very clear (to me) what is meant by "both working all the time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard synchronisation techniques will not achieve what you require. That is, concurrent updates to the queue. This is because when one thread acquires a lock on the queue, another thread then cannot acquire a lock on the queue and so cannot proceed.

The technique that you have to implement in order to achieve concurrent updates to the queue is called **lock stripping**. This is how concurrent collections such as `ConcurrentHashMap` achieve concurrent reads and writes. Implementing lock stripping is not trivial.

You need to ask yourself whether if implementing a custom collection with lock stripping will be easier than if you choose a JDK collection such as `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.